# Chrome: Breakpoint when location.href is set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Is there a way to have Chrome's debugger pause whenever location.href is changed? Some code is causing navigation on my page, and I can't figure out where the actual navigation is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the initiator page and line number in the Network panel if you check 'Preserve log', which preserves the log between loads:

[image: Network Panel]
[image: Source Code]

As you can see, the network Panel has a request originating from `test.html` at line number 3. In my source code, I find the rouge redirect there.